# optimizing parallel webservice calls

Tags: c#

In my project I have an `async` method `AnAsynWebServiceCallHere` for calling a web service. I want to call `AnAsynWebServiceCallHere` twice in parallel and at the end I want to return the combined result. Will at the end of this method

```
public async Task<List<DesiredResult>> GetMyDesiredData(MyParamDTO dto)
{
  List<DesiredResult> list = new List<DesiredResult>();
  await Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(()=> {var result1 = AnAsynWebServiceCallHere(dto.A);list.Add(result1);}), 
    Task.Run(()=> {var result2 = AnAsynWebServiceCallHere(dto.A);list.Add(result2);})
  );
  return list;
}
```

and body of the '' method is:

```
public async Task<DesiredResult> AnAsynWebServiceCallHere(string sqlQuery)
{
  string json;
  using(HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://demoapi.MyHost.net/SQLRunner"))
  {
      request.Headers.Add("id", SECURITY_TOKEN);          
      request.Headers.Add("sqlStatement", sqlQuery);
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
      json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesiredResult>(json);
}
```

Is the written method an elegant approach?

**Update:**
Context provided with the called method body.

Comment: We cannot tell you whether this is an elegant approach or not becase this code isn't real and we don't review pseudo/hypothetical code.

Comment: This is a real code, just changed the method and object names from my real project. is the down-vote due to this reason?

Comment: Yes, the DV is for that reason and for not sharing enough context e.g. we don't know what's the signature of `AnAsynWebServiceCallHere`.

Comment: q@t3chb0t question updated

Comment: Why is it still on-hold? I am curious. I did everything to make it off-hold.

Comment: I find this still looks very much like pseudocode and thus voted against reopening but some people are of a different opinion so it might get reopened soon...

Answer (score 1):

If `AnAsynWebServiceCallHere` is already async then there is no need for the additional `Task.Run` in the `Task.WhenAll`.

[`Task.WhenAll<TResult>(param Task<TResult>[])`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0____) will already return the results of the tasks in the collection as an array of results.

All that is left then is to convert the array to a `List<>`

```
public async Task<List<DesiredResult>> GetMyDesiredData(MyParamDTO dto) {
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        AnAsynWebServiceCallHere(dto.A), 
        AnAsynWebServiceCallHere(dto.A)
    );
    return results.ToList();
}
```

All the tasks will run in parallel and at the end will return the combined results.

Looking at the `AnAsynWebServiceCallHere` you could also wrap the response in a `using` statement as it is disposable also

```
public async Task<DesiredResult> AnAsynWebServiceCallHere(string sqlQuery) {
    var url = "https://demoapi.MyHost.net/SQLRunner";
    using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)) {
        request.Headers.Add("id", SECURITY_TOKEN);          
        request.Headers.Add("sqlStatement", sqlQuery);
        using(HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesiredResult>(json);
        }
    }      
}
```